# Is there a way to hide the chat feature in the person-card component?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, web-parts, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm developing an Employee Directory web part for a client (SPO) using Microsoft Graph Toolkit. They don't want the "start a chat" feature to show on the person-card component. Is there a way to hide that section?

I've searched through the issues on GitHub to see if anyone else has asked this question but couldn't find anything. Could not find anything on google either. Any ideas?